# Angular sequenced router animation

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I am new to angular animation. I would like to test out a router animation which have multiple stages of animation.

[image: home page]

1st page(home page) have 3 blocks of divs with different colors. If we click on one of it it will scale to width of it becomes 100% with a smoothly.

After becoming 100% if need to show a some text in the middle for few seconds.

[image: 1st part of the animation done]

Right After that the next page have to show from middle to enlarged square animation

[image: The 1st part of the 2nd animation showing a part of next page]

[image: Showing some more next page]

[image: 2nd animation is done]

For example it have to go through following steps :

The enlarging box have to show as the next page was already behind the 1st page already.

For more clearance, check this [websites](https://www.tentwenty.me/) tile click animation

I would like to do this task from angular animations, and i am new to doing this kind of complex step by step animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not achieve this by one animation, but i used 2 animated components to get this done.

For the revealing box animation, I had to write animation in app component.

app.component.html =>

```
<app-header></app-header>

<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/next">next</a>
</nav>
<div id="page" class="routeContainer" [@routeAnimation]="getDepth(myOutlet)">
  <router-outlet #myOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts =>

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {animate, group, query, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      transition('1 => 2', [
        // animate the leave page away
        group([
          query(
            ':enter',
            [
              style({
                position: 'absolute',
                'z-index' : '100',
                opacity: 1,
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                'clip-path': 'polygon(100px 400px, 400px 400px , 400px 500px, 100px 500px)'

              }),
              animate(
                '3s cubic-bezier(.35,0,.25,1)',
                style({
                  opacity: 1,
                  'clip-path': 'polygon(0px 0px, 100% 0px , 100% 100%, 0px 100%)'
                   })
              ),
            ],
            { optional: true }
          ),
          query(
            ':leave',
            [animate('2s', style({ opacity: 1, 'z-index': '0', }))],
            { optional: true }
          )
        ])
      ]),

    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  getDepth(outlet) {
    return outlet.activatedRouteData['depth'];
  }


}
```

In the routing we declare depth value of each route, like this =>

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: MainComponent, data: {depth: 1} },
  { path: 'next', component: NextComponent, data: {depth: 2} }

];
```

For curtain animation, I wrote animation inside MainComponent separately.

main.component.html

```
<div class="row main-page">


  <div  [ngClass] ="{'link1-animation' :helpMenuOpen, 'col-sm link1' :!helpMenuOpen }"  (click)="toggle()"
        [@slideInOut]="helpMenuOpen"
        (@slideInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"

  >

    <h1>
      123
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm link2">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm link3">
  </div>
</div>
```

main.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('true', style({
        'z-index': 2,
        width: '100%',
        left: 0,
        'background-color': 'pink'
      })),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('1s ease'))
    ])
  ]
})


export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public helpMenuOpen = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle() {
    this.helpMenuOpen = !this.helpMenuOpen ;

  }


  animationDone($event) {

    if (this.helpMenuOpen) {

      this.router.navigate(['/next']);
    }

  }


}
```

What I did was wait till the curtain animation is completed and navigate to the next page. When the navigation occurs route animation which I did above will run.